# Como assegurar que um elemento terá o evento DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Boa tarde,

Hoje estou enfrentando um bug bastante estranho em minha aplicação:

Eu possuo um campo do tipo textarea onde eu digito um corpo de email e logo abaixo do mesmo um botão que quando é clicado obtêm o conteúdo da textarea, abre um modal e insere o mesmo conteúdo(value) dentro do body do modal.

A questão é que alguns usuários estão reportando que o botão abre o modal porém não insere o value do textarea dentro do mesmo.

Ao analisar essa questão identifiquei que não é sempre que isso ocorre, quando dá problema, se você atualizar a página a função tende a funcionar.

Quando dá erro, ao inspecionar os eventos de click do botão percebo que o mesmo foi substituído por uma função do BootStrap JS ou simplesmente nenhuma outra função é substituída.

**Como posso fazer para assegurar que isso não ocorra?**

```
  $('#btnPreviewEmail').click(function(){
  var assunto  = $('#txtAssuntoEmail').val();
  var texto    = CKEDITOR.instances['txtAreaCorpoDoEmail'].getData();
  var namepage = 'Campanha Marketing Lojas Uno';
  var landing  = buscaLandingPorNamePage(namepage);
  assunto = assunto.replace(/{{.FirstName}}/g, "Renoir dos Reis");
  assunto = assunto.replace(/{{.DataHoje}}/g, '31/10/2016');
  texto   = texto.replace(/{{.FirstName}}/g, "Renoir dos Reis");
  texto   = texto.replace(/{{.Tracker}}/g, "");
  texto   = texto.replace(/{{.URL}}/g, landing);
  texto   = texto.replace(/{{.DataHoje}}/g, '31/10/2016');
  $('#containerAssunto').html(assunto);
  $('#containerPreview').html(texto);
});
```

**Código do botão que abre o modal:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="btnPreviewEmail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalPreview">Pre-visualizar</button>
```

**Modal:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Podes colocar o HTML e código que vai buscar o valor da textarea?

Comment: Qual é a linha que vai buscar o valor? é o texto ou o assunto?

Comment: @Sergio ambos serão buscados

Comment: Mas ambos vêm de uma `texarea` e têm problemas a aparecer no modal?

Comment: @Sergio, o txtAreaCorpoDoEmail é um textarea do CKEDITOR, e o assunto vem de um input type="text". Ambos não aparecem no modal.

Comment: E o código que de fato abre o modal?

Comment: @bfavaretto inseri os detalhes que faltavam.

Comment: No console do browser (F12) aparece algum erro?

Comment: @bfavaretto não :(.

Comment: Tudo indica que você tenta colocar conteúdo no modal antes do bootstrap deixar esse modal pronto. Pode ser isso, pode não ser. Tente colocar esse código em um `$('#modalPreview').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) { /* COD AQUI */ })` em vez de colocar no clique do botão

Comment: Esse botão `btnPreviewEmail` é criado dinamicamente? Tenta substituir `$('#btnPreviewEmail').click(function(){` por `$('#btnPreviewEmail').on('click', function(){`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Já tentou utilizar o evento click desta maneira?

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnPreviewEmail", function(){
    /*Seu Código*/
});
```

O código deve estar fora do PageLoad do script.

Diferença entre o `.on("click")` e `.click()` -

`.on("click")`:

- Ele pode trabalhar dinâmicamente com elementos que foram criados de
  posteriormente na página.
- Só é carregado quando o evento é acionado.
- Deve ser usado em um elemento pai, que esteja na página desde o PageLoad, pra buscar a partir dele o elemento que vai ser criado dinamicamente (por isso `$(document).on()` e não `$('#btnPreviewEmail').on()`

`.click()`

- Não pode ser acionado caso você tenha criado um elemento
  posteriormente em sua página.
- É carregado mesmo que o elemento não seja acionado.

Mais detalhes:
[Referencia em Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click)

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Thales, se faltou só explicar qual a diferença entre esse e o atalho .click(). Assim alguém que acessar essa dúvida pode ter uma resposta melhor pautada na documentação.

Comment: Excelente trabalho, mas o meu manipulador era referenciado após a criação do elemento. Logo, qualquer um teria de funcionar.