# Como ativar o onclick depois de um jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, eventos

Tenho uns `botões` que são montados dinamicamente via `jquery`, acontece que na página principal tenho uns eventos desses `botões`, mas como eles ainda não existem no momento do carregamento da pagina os eventos não são carregados, eu precisava fazer algo como um refresh nesses eventos assim que o `jquery` fosse carregado.

Código:

```
Abre Pagina HTML
$(".meusbtns").click(function...);
Monta HTML Basico
Clica numa lista e essa lista traz o result por um jquery
<button class="meusbtns" value="x">Botao</button>
```

Perceba que a classe `meusbtns` exite, mas como ela veio pelo `jquery` o evento não foi carregado inicialmente.

Sei que existe como adicionar e retirar classes, o que resetaria o evento, mas como esses botões são dinamicos não imagino como fazer dessa forma.

Espero ter sido claro

Comment: Há várias perguntas sobre isso... uma delas é: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/36812/129

Comment: Outra pergunta interessante para este problema é http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5196/129

Answer (score 4):

Segue uma outra pergunta referente ao mesmo assunto:

[Como assegurar que um elemento terá o evento DOM?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/162489/como-assegurar-que-um-elemento-ter%C3%A1-o-evento-dom/162500#162500)

Utilize fora do pageLoad:

```
$(document).on("click", ".meusbtns", function(){
    /*Seu Código*/
});
```

A função `.on("click"):` pode trabalhar dinâmicamente com elementos que foram criados de posteriormente na página.

Answer (score 0):

Simples, você tem que fazer o bind desses eventos de click depois de montar os botões.

Exemplo:

```
function montaView() {
  ... // supondo que você tenha montado seus botoes
  bindEventos();
}

function bindEventos() {
  ... // faz o bind dos eventos
}
```

### Atenção!

Caso você chame o evento de bind em um elemento que ja tenha seus binds, ele vai fazer o bind de novo e o evento será executado x vezes que vc fez o bind. Para evitar isso você pode usar o `.off()` para remover o evento previamente bindado e refazer o bind.

Exemplo:

```
botoesNaoDinamicos.off('click');
todosOsBotoes.click(...);
```